# (How) Can I use string substitution for working w/ Django’s i18n {% trans %} tag?

Tags: python, django, formatting, templates, internationalization

I'm looking for something like this:

`{% trans "There are %{flowers}n flowers in the vase" < flowers:3 %}`

Now obviously syntax is fake, but it should be sufficient to demonstrate what I'm looking for.

Should I cook something of my own? It looks like a common usecase, so I was quite surprised that quick web search didn't return anything helpful.

I'm actually starting to loathe working with Django templating system... While I understand that it's designed to enforce separation of application logic from view, it's doing it by being intrusive on my workflow. I should be able to quickly prototype and only when I need to work with designer, and only then, should I have to be more strict about something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure what you're trying to do (what's `< flowers:3` supposed to do?), but have you looked at [blocktrans](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#specifying-translation-strings-in-template-code)?

```
{% blocktrans count flowers|length as counter %}
    There is one flower in the vase.
{% plural %}
    There are {{ counter }} flowers in the vase.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: Equal to "... %s ... " % substitution.. Just thought yet another "%" would be ambiguous. Now of course blocktrans is exactly what I need. Can't figure how I missed it? Oh well, got to be more careful next time. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`{% blocktrans %}`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/internationalization/#specifying-translation-strings-in-template-code) instead of `{% trans %}`.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the module [inflect.py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect) useful, although it would mean departing from the templating system.

```
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()
p.num(numflowers, show=False)
return 'There %s %s %s in the vase.' % (
              p.pl('is'),
              p.numwords(numflowers),
              p.pl('flower'))
```

with numflowers = 1

```
'There is one flower in the vase.'
```

with numflowers = 2

```
'There are two flowers in the vase.'
```